# Kernel does NOT recognize NAND bad blocks marked by u-boot

Tags: embedded-linux, u-boot

While in u-boot of my ARM based board (DM368) I mark some kernel partition block manually as bad. U-boot says that it was marked and, for example, while writing/reading kernel image I see it skipping this bad block.

But when I try to write the same partition from within Linux (loaded via NFS) I see that Linux nandwrite command USES this bad block! I checked this in several ways - Linux ignores bad block mark for 100%. But everywhere in the internet it is said that BBT is one for both u-boot and Linux.

So, where is the catch?

Comment: How are you writing the partition and what is the filing system on top of it?

Comment: OK, I wanted to be short...:-)
I am looking to update kernel from within kernel.

Initial kernel is written by u-boot, which skips bad blocks - tested by marking block as bad and rewriting the image.
Now, from within kernel (loaded via NFS) I nanddump3 kernel image with OOB with -bb=skipbad once and without -bb - the result is the same exactly. I also made nandwrite3 -o and write it back. When there was no bad block marked artificially, everything worked fine. But now, with the bad block marked, u-boot cannot load kernel - CRC error.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, the answer is found.
For some unclear reason Texas Instruments, manufacturer of the board DM365EVM which I use for development, provides the kernel with different BBT structure. They defined BBT offset as 2, while all the world, including the provided u-boot, defines this offset as 8.
I wish them a good health for many years.

Comment: Any chance you could point us to the file/line/define where you need to make the change? I too know the pain of Ti's SDK codebase and wish them many blessings.

Comment: Try to look into the file board-dm365-dvr.c. There are the definitions of the struct nand_bbt_descr...